# An internal error occurred during: "Launching testng.xml" while running testng suite

Tags: eclipse

**Environment details**

- **Eclipse Version**: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
- **Project**: maven project
- **Testing Dependency Version**: 6.14.3
- **Testing Eclipse Plugin Version**: 6.14.0.2

Problem - My initial version of testng was 6.14.3, then i tried to upgrade to the latest version 7.0.0-beta5,got some error. 
Then I put dependency of 7.0.0-beta4 in pom file, there was no error in building and compilation.When I tried to run testng.xml file, I get following error.
Then I again put dependancy of 6.14.3 for testng and updated maven project, but stll getting same issue.

```
'Launching temp_testng.xml' has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during: "Launching temp_testng.xml".

plugin- org.eclipse.core.jobs
**Exception stack trace**

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.getClasspath(Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;)Ljava/util/List;
    at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getClasspath(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:350)
    at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.createVMRunner(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:192)
    at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launchTypes(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:157)
    at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Im my testng.xml file I am getting yellow mark at line .So is this causing above error while execution?

Tried following solutions to fix the above issue, but unable to resolve the issue.

1. Re-installed TestNG plugin multiple times
2. uninstalling of the optional M2E from TestNG plugin
3. Project>Build path>Source>removed source folders and added again
4. Cleaned .m2 repository and build/updated maven workspace again
5. Created new workspace and sample testng project with only one class
6. Re-installed eclipse

Struggling to resolve this error, If anyone knows how to fix this configuration issue Please Help!

[image: internal error]